# flush timeoutError in fluentd

Tags: logging, fluentd

I am running `fluentd` with following config:

```
<source>
    @type forward
    port 24224
</source>
<filter docker.**>
    @type concat
    key msg
    stream_identity_key uuid
    multiline_start_regexp /url:/
    multiline_end_regexp /.* ---$/
</filter>
<match docker.**>
    @type copy
    <store>
        @type stdout
    </store>
</match>
```

I am getting below `Fluent::ConcatFilter::TimeoutError` when some `event` occurs:

```
2016-05-11 15:22:38 +0530 [warn]: dump an error event: error_class=Fluent::ConcatFilter::TimeoutError error="Timeout flush: docker.containers:67deabd67c04199d" tag="docker.containers" time=1462960358 record={"msg"=>"url: /get/image.jpg\nid: 83110292-24a4-62a8-c155-ebc0f9bbb976"}
2016-05-11 15:22:38 +0530 [info]: Timeout flush: docker.containers:67deabd67c04199d
```

Could anyone please tell me why this error is coming and how to resolve it

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the issue on the github repository, you will find the answer [here](https://github.com/okkez/fluent-plugin-concat/issues/4#issuecomment-238085219)

You need to add a time out label in your configuration  to process entries

Comment: An illustration of a setup that utilizes your current outputs for both normal logs and failed logs can be found at a similar, but separate github issue: https://github.com/fluent-plugins-nursery/fluent-plugin-concat/issues/7#issuecomment-274048892

Answer (score -2):

I'm a developer of `fluent-plugin-concat`.

It seems that just timeout is occurred (for each flush_interval).

If timeout is occurred, fluent-plugin-concat emits an error event.
This is the spec of fluent-plugin-concat.

Comment: Add more details to your answer.

Comment: I believe fluent-plugin-concat only emits the error event when there is no way to catch the errors. If you add a label and something to catch the label the error goes away.